# Erl cannot connect to local EPMD. Why?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

```
Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [rq:1] [async-threads:0 [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8.5  (abort with ^G)

[root@ip-10-101-61-85 ec2-user]# erl -sname foo
{error_logger,{{2012,12,7},{3,17,8}},"Protocol: ~p: register error: ~p~n",["inet_tcp",{{badmatch,{error,epmd_close}},[{inet_tcp_dist,listen,1},{net_kernel,start_protos,4},{net_kernel,start_protos,3},{net_kernel,init_node,2},{net_kernel,init,1},{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,12,7},{3,17,8}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{net_kernel,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.20.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{error,badarg},[{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.9.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[#Port<0.55>,<0.17.0>]},{dictionary,[{longnames,false}]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,377},{stack_size,24},{reductions,453}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2012,12,7},{3,17,8}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{'EXIT',nodistribution}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_kernel},{mfargs,{net_kernel,start_link,[[foo,shortnames]]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,12,7},{3,17,8}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,shutdown},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,12,7},{3,17,8}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

I am working fine on my local machine but not on Amazon EC2, I wonder if it is some network related problem.

How can I check it? The EPMD log keep say my connection is from non-local address and block.

This would affect my RabbitMQ start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a bug. Newer erlang versions restrict connections to epmd to local addresses by default. Most likely you have had routing issues or the reason is to masquerade all outgoing traffic with iptables without checking if the destination is 127.0.0.0/8.

Adjust your MASQUERADE rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j MASQUERADE
```

And/Or check your routing table.

Comment: That would be an ipfw rule I guess. I have no access to a Mac at the moment but `man ipfw` should help you get started.

Comment: is there an option to disable masquerade for single port?

Comment: There are the `--dport`  and `--sport` options to make rules port specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to your hostname setting.

```
[root@ip-10-101-61-85 ec2-user]# erl -sname foo
```

According to your above shell information, the current host name is `"ip-10-101-61-85 ec2-user"`, it may be allocated by the OS installation program. 
Try to reset your hostname, and not use `whitespace` in the host name and try again.

Comment: ip-10-101-61-85 should be the hostname, ec2-user should be the current user name

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a bug for erlang R14 or above on CentOS Ec2, i am working fine on erlang R13 now