# Starting erlang without fully qualified hostnames in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, erlang

when starting erlang on my local machine I am able to do

`erl -name testnode`

this starts up an erlang node with the fully qualified hostname of my machine

```
~ erl -name test
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source-d2a6d81] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.3  (abort with ^G)
(test@laptop.hanahaus.com)1>
```

when I do the same thing on AWS I get back

```
({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Can you paste the config file without the credentials for your erlang on the AWS EC2

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756463/erl-cannot-connect-to-local-epmd-why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need fully qualified hostnames in your Erlang node names, you can use `-sname` instead of `-name`:

```
erl -sname testnode
```

(to be clear, it seems like the the Erlang node cannot determine its FQDN for some reason, and using `-sname` instead of `-name` works around this problem by removing the need for FQDNs.)

Comment: -sname will not work I would like to start my process on multiple instances and create a cluster - this will not happen with -sname

Comment: I was wrong - you were right :) some ports need to be opened - but eventually I got a cluster up and running :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not fqdn problem. This is network issue. Disable firewall and try to start again.